# Trying to make an automated table right-alligned - Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

So this is what I got so far...

```
r = int(input("How many rows?\n"))#Inputs amount of row
c = int(input("How many columns?\n"))#Input amount of columns
largest = (len(str(r**c)))#Multiplying r, c amount of times

for i in range(1,r+1):
    for y in range(1,c+1):
        numb = i**y
        space = " " * ((largest - len(str(numb))))
        print(numb, end=space)
    print ()
```

And this prints like so

```
How many rows?
5
How many columns?
6
1    1    1    1    1    1    
2    4    8    16   32   64   
3    9    27   81   243  729  
4    16   64   256  1024 4096 
5    25   125  625  3125 15625
```

Trying to make it right-aligned so it looks something like this

```
1      1     1     1     1     1    
2      4     8    16    32    64   
3      9    27    81   243   729  
4     16    64   256  1024  4096 
5     25   125   625  3125 15625
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `str.format` to right-align items in a string

```
def printer(rows, cols):
    for i in range(1, rows+1):
        print(('{:>10}'*cols).format(*[i**j for j in range(1, cols+1)]))
```

`printer(5, 6)` will then print

```
         1         1         1         1         1         1
         2         4         8        16        32        64
         3         9        27        81       243       729
         4        16        64       256      1024      4096
         5        25       125       625      3125     15625
```

Comment: I like the * cols, cleaner than using joins for string of list!

Answer (score 0):

This should solve your problem

```
for i in range(1,r+1):
    for y in range(1,c+1):
        numb = i**y
        space = " " * ((largest - len(str(numb))))
        print("{}{}".format(space, numb))
```

Comment: Wow thanks guys, new to this site but damn is it friendly

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this would be with string alignment (assuming you do not need Python 2):

```
r = 6
c = 6

for i in range(1,r+1):
    numbs = [i**y for y in range(1,c+1)]
    print(
        '  '.join(['{:>12}'.format(y**i) for y in range(1,c+1)])
    )
```

Prints

```
   1             1             1             1             1             1
   2             4             8            16            32            64
   3             9            27            81           243           729
   4            16            64           256          1024          4096
   5            25           125           625          3125         15625
   6            36           216          1296          7776         46656
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to figure out the spacing is by looking at the last bottom right value of the table. As this will always be the largest value and so determine the amount of spacing you need.

You can do this by checking the length of the last number and using this as the argument for formatting. (note that the `last` variable has been turned into a string for the `len()` process to work). Also remember that the last number is row to the power of column, where these values are what was inputted.

```
last = r**c
lastLen = len(str(last))
spacing = str(lastLen) + "d"
```

Then all you have to change is the way you currently output your values from...

```
print(numb, end=space)
```

...to this which uses `format()` to use the arguments you have found!

```
print(format(numb,spacing), end=" ")
```