# How to display number sequences in rows and columns in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numbers, multiple-columns, rows

I have a coding assignment to input row and column length, and create a power table.  THe example below is for 5 rows, 5 columns.

[image]

The code I have so far prints the correct number of rows and columns, but I haven't been able to get the calculations to work.  It just shows a table of 1's, five by five.

```
rows = int(input("Enter a number of rows: "))
cols = int(input("Enter a number of columns: "))

x = 1
y = 1
z = 1

line = ""

while x <= cols :
    line = line + format(y**cols, "4d")
    x = x + 1
while z <= rows :
    print(line)
    z = z + 1
```

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47276353/6779307

Answer (score 1):

The basic problem is that you need to nest your loops.  Your second problem is that you never change `y`.  What you do at the moment is to compute the power sequence for `1` into five different lines -- and then you print that *last line only* five times.  Try two changes:

1. Compute a line, then print it immediately.  *Then* you go to the next line.
2. Use the correct variable.

After changes:

```
while z <= rows:
    while x <= cols:
        line = line + format(x**cols, "4d")   # Note the variable change
        x = x + 1
        print(line)

    z = z + 1
```

Also, look up the `for` statement, as this will simplify things.  After that, look up `list comprehension` for even more compression.

Answer (score 0):

Instead, try creating a 2D array in Python such as a 2D list.

```
Matrix = [[0 for x in range(5)] for y in range(5)] 
    for i in range(5):
        for j in range(5):
            Matrix[i][j]=j^i
```

Then, print the data you need using nested `for` loops.

```
for i in range (5):
    for j in range(5):
        print(Matrix[j][i])
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do it that preserves padding no matter what:

```
def grid(rows, cols, padding):
  max_num_len = len(str(rows**cols))
  return '\n'.join([
    ''.join(['{{:>{}}}'.format(max_num_len+padding).format((row+1)**(col+1))
             for col in range(cols)])
    for row in range(rows)
  ])

print(grid(5, 5, 3))
```